# Ignore internal properties in ShouldBeEquivalentTo

Tags: c#, tdd, fluent-assertions, object-graph

Is there a way to ignore internal properties of a class when doing ShouldBeEquivalentTo?

For example, in the class below I want to exclude the MetaData property from the object graph comparison.

```
public class SomeObject 
{
    Public string SomeString { get; set; }
    internal MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

I would prefer to not use

```
someObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(someOtherObject, options =>     
    options.Excluding(info => info.SelectedMemberPath == "MetaData")
```

Because I might have more than 1 internal property and setting up this for all those properties would be tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`IMemberSelectionRule`](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions/blob/77be654857b4ba28e75709a97a481b24fe966dcc/Src/Core/Equivalency/IMemberSelectionRule.cs) interface in the FluentAssertions library:

> Represents a rule that defines which members of the subject-under-test to include while comparing two objects for structural equality.

Implementing this interface allows to exclude all the *internal* properties at once (where [`IsAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) property is `true`):

```
  internal class AllExceptNonPublicPropertiesSelectionRule : IMemberSelectionRule
  {
    public bool IncludesMembers
    {
      get { return false; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectedMemberInfo> SelectMembers(
      IEnumerable<SelectedMemberInfo> selectedMembers,
      ISubjectInfo context,
      IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
    {
      return selectedMembers.Except(
        config.GetSubjectType(context)
          .GetNonPrivateProperties()
          .Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsAssembly)
          .Select(SelectedMemberInfo.Create));
    }
  }
```

Now the rule can be utilized in unit tests:

```
  someObject.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(someOtherObject, options => options.Using(
    new AllExceptNonPublicPropertiesSelectionRule()));
```